# Find an error in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

When i am building my solution there is an error that show in the error panel.
But i don't understand the error and the real problem is when i am clicking on the error it doesn't taking me to error line.

In the error table the fields File, Line, Column and Project are empty.
So how can i find where is my problem?

I have already done a research for the words "Ticks" and didn't found anything

[image]

Comment: My guess would be that you're using a slider and you set one of the properties incorrectly.

Comment: What do the first few Google hits tell you? [Here](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2010/03/solved-error-1-ticks-must-be-between.html), [here](http://www.k2underground.com/forums/t/9079.aspx), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496148/compile-error-ticks-must-be-between-datetime-minvalue-ticks-and-datetime-maxval). A little more information about your solution (what kind of project(s) and so on) would be nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile Error: Ticks must be between DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks. Parameter name: ticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496148/compile-error-ticks-must-be-between-datetime-minvalue-ticks-and-datetime-maxval)

Comment: Also, is this WPF?  That makes a HUGE difference.

Comment: What type of project is it? Which .NET Framework is the code running on? 4.0?

Comment: What's your VS Version and What's the warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, pretty strange.
Refer to this [blog post](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2010/03/solved-error-1-ticks-must-be-between.html):

> How I Solved It After getting pretty annoyed because I was on the
>   clock I made a backup of the site and decided to delete files until
>   the dodgy file showed its face.
>
> I used the following heuristic to do this:
>
> 1.Switch to the Output tab and see what the last folder was which was compiled before it borked. 
>   2.Delete that folder. 
>   3.Recompile
>   4.Keep repeating steps 1 to 3 until the site compiles
>   5.When it compiles start bringing back individual files in the last batch you deleted until you find the offending file For me it turned
>   out to be a single .jpg which when viewed in explorer with View
>   Details had an empty "Date Modified".
>
> I opened it up in Photoshop and saved it out again and this fixed the
>   problem.